# Matlab matrix string manipulation

Tags: string, matlab

When I have a matrix, which has values written like 5.34000E+5. When I try to create a string variable, with the following value mat(1,1), which contains the 5.340000E+5, Matlab creates a string variable with 534000. How can I create a string variable like 5.34000E+5?

Thanks

Comment: How do you create the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [specify the formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#btf97wk) while converting:

```
>> number = 534000
number =  534000
>> s = num2str(number,'%10.5e\n')
s =

5.34000e+05

>> class(s)
ans = char
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf`

```
num = 534000;
str = sprintf('%.0f',num);
str2 = sprintf('%e',num);
disp(str);
disp(str2);
```

Here, `%` means that you want to specify format, `f` means float and `.0` means that you want no decimals `e` means that you want it as exponential. For more info on this see [sprintf format specifiers](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec).